# Why Hibernate ManyToOne is not persisted correctly?

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-one

I have two entities User and Wish :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_USER")
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Column(length = 50)
    private String lastname;

    @Column(length = 50)
    private String firstname;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user",cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    private Set<Wish> wishes = new HashSet<Wish>();

    // getters and setters

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "T_WISH")
public class Wish implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;


    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @ManyToOne
    private User user;

    // getters and setters

    }
```

When i save the user, recruiter_id is null why. I've tried :

```
Wish wish = wishRepository.save(wish);
        user.getWishes.add(wish);
    User userSaved =    userRepository.save(user);
```

Why the recruiter_id is not set.

Comment: What recruiter_id? I don't see any of that in the code you posted.

Answer (score 0):

Your user class does not have @Id anottated field.